# Alt tags not displaying properly in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

this is my first post so i hope i'm being clear. Basically i'm having a problem in IE where the Alt tag text will only display on the first hover. In other words, if i hover over the image i get a nice tool tip displaying the information i need, after around 10 seconds this disappears. Which is fine, but then when i go to hover back over the image...no alt text is displayed.

this is dynamically drawn in the backend (c#)

```
s += "<img src=\"../../images/littleinfo.gif\" alt=\"" + Line.Description + "\" class=\"blackparagraphlink\"/>";
```

Whats even more strange is that this is only happening with certain users (all of our clients use IE) and appears on both IE7 and 8 (but only randomly, it isn't a problem on the machine i use...but is a problem on a machine that is at the other end of the office...both using IE8). I've checked compatibility settings, and they are turned off (i have tried turning these on...but the problem still remains).

the CSS class that the image links to doesn't seem to effect this issue either. Has anyone else come across this strange problem? I've searched high and low on the web, and this is my final attempt at solving the issue.

any help is much appreciated.

Alex :)

Comment: If you output `Line.description` on it's own, is it always what you expect it to be?  Or if you `view source` on one of the computers that isn't doing it, is the expected `alt` tag in there?

Comment: Hi Richard, sorry i havent replied sooner. Yes i've tried that, i tried doing both on the machines that show this error and both fail on title and the alt tag.

Answer (score 6):

`Alt` attributes are not supposed to hover in the first place. They are only used if the image didn't load.

Use the `title` attribute instead which is designed specifically for this. Just change `alt` to `title` in your code. Then add a real `alt` attribute describing what the image looks like. (Whatever littleinfo.gif is.)

PS. png's are much smaller than gifs. Use png unless you need animation.

Comment: Ok thanks, i've tried using Title (just getting a client to test it now) i know using alt tags isnt the best way, but this is quite a large system which has been using the alt tags for years (so i cant really just go in and change everything). thanks for the help :)

Comment: hmmmmm Title seems to exhibit the same behaviour. (i.e. its just the same). do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly worth adding to your answer that `alt` tags are used for a description of the image, which is used by screen-readers, so not only for when the image doesn't load.

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp) link explains the `alt` attribute, you should use the `title` attribute if you want to display a tooltip.

> Internet Explorer also displays the value of the alt attribute as a tooltip when mousing over the image. This is NOT the correct behavior, according to the HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

ie display alt on hover and title if they are no alt 
firefox display only title on hover and not alt.